# How to make a non-modal Dialog window be always on top?

Tags: qt, qml

I am using an instance of a `Dialog {}` in my application to display a small controller window that the user can interact with to affect the functions in the main window (sort of a remote control). I can make this Dialog modal (`modality: Qt.WindowModal` or `modality: Qt.ApplicationModal`) or I can make it non-modal with `modality: Qt.NonModal`.

My problem is that I need to make it non-modal but be always on top of the main window. If I use `Qt.NonModal` I can still click on the main form but then my Dialog goes behind it. The `Dialog` class does not seem to have a `flags:` property, so I can't just set it to `Qt.WindowsStaysOnTopHint`.

Is there any way to set the flags of a Dialog like this purely from the QML side? Or is it possible to write a simple utility method in c++ that I could call from my Dialog's `Component.onCompleted:` and pass in the dialog to set its windows flags there?

Update: to illustrate what I'm talking about, here is my dialog on top of my main window:

[image]

Here is my dialog underneath my main window:

[image]

I want my dialog to not go underneath my main window like this, but I still want to be able to click on and interact with my main window. In other words, I want my dialog to be non-modal, but always-on-top.

Comment: Maybe you could just filter out the click events outside the Dialog with a MouseArea?

Comment: @sk2212: I don't think that would work. I want the use to be able to click on and interact with either the main window or this floating remote. Basically just standard tool window behavior.

Comment: Hmm...could you please create a simple screenshot from your window and dialog? I still do not get your point.

Comment: Is the main window the parent of the `Dialog`?  That *should* be enough to keep the `Dialog` on top -- I think.

Comment: @G.M.: the main window is the parent of the Dialog (I think, it's defined in-line at the moment) but it still goes under the main window.

Comment: @sk2212: added screenshots, but this is just standard tool window behavior: non-modal but always on top. I just don't know how to achieve this in QML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use [`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) instead of [`Dialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html) this way you will have access to the [`flags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#flags-prop) property.

You can set [`flags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#flags-prop) to `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` to have your window always on top of other ones. You can find the list of flags [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum). (Don't forget to replace the `::` by `.` in QML)

*Main.qml :*

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Button {
        id: btn
        width: 100 ; height : 40
        text: "click me"
    }

    Text {
        anchors.top : btn.bottom
        text: "Button currently pressed"
        visible: btn.pressed
    }

    DialogOnTop {

    }
}
```

*DialogOnTop.qml :*

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: myWindow

    width: 200
    height: 200

    flags:  Qt.Window | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
            | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
            | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint


    visible: true
    modality: Qt.NonModal // no need for this as it is the default value


    Rectangle {
        color: "lightskyblue"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            text: "Hello !"
            color: "navy"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

*Result :*

[image: always on top window]

Comment: So my earlier attempt at using Window was failing inexplicably on `createComponent` (this was the error about the non-existent flags and modality properties) but when I created a new class based on your example the Window worked perfectly. The app I'm working on is a codebase inherited from other developers, and they seem to have added some magical under-the-hood code in c++ that replaces the real `Window` class in QML with their own version (that does not publicly expose the flags and modality, hence the error). Once I commented out their import statements in my class, the `Window` works ...

Comment: ... perfectly, non-modal and always on top of my main window. Sometimes I hate my fellow developers, but *you* I like. I'm going to add a bounty to this question which you will get (I was about to put a bounty on this anyway to help me get an answer).

Answer (score 2):

Usually you want to use the `Dialog` not just to create a new window, but for its implemented functionality and interface...

The reason that the `Dialog` does not inherit `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` is obvious: There is no window, as long as it is not `open()`. But once it is open, there is a `ApplicationWindow` (from QtQuick.Controls 1.4)

Now, in the documentation we find this nice attatched property: `ApplicationWindow` which is available to every `Item`, and conveniently it allows us to access the window. Then we just need to find a way, to set the right flags, as soon as the `ApplicationWindow` becomes available - e.g. when we get the signal `visibleChanged`.
As the `Dialog` is no `Item` either, we need to use its `contentItem` to access this attached property.

When we put all of this together the result might look like this:

**NonModalDialogThatStaysOnTop.qml** *// I suck at naming*

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 // You need this, to have access to the `ApplicationWindow`-attatched property
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Dialog {
    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (visible) contentItem.ApplicationWindow.window.flags |= Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
    }
    modality: "NonModal"
}
```

Now you have your favorite `Dialog` that stays on top but is not modal.

Comment: It works! However, it works only with QtQuick.Controls 1st generation import (not second). Also I had to add a pair of other flags to have title and close button visible: Qt.WindowTitleHint and Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you simply want to create a Dialog (or a Component which looks like a Dialog) and just want to interact with the Main window *and* the Dialog window.

Please try the following:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    color: "green"

    Rectangle {
        id: behind
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0,  0.7)
        visible: false
    }

    MouseArea {
        enabled: behind.visible
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            console.log("Root Window")
        }
    }

    Button {

        text: "Open Dialog"

        onClicked: {
            behind.visible = true;
            var comp = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyDialog.qml");
            // var comp = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/DialogQt.qml");
            var obj1 = comp.createObject(rootWindow, {});
            obj1.z = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

MyDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    id: modalWindow
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "red"

    anchors.centerIn: parent

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Modal Window")
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking on 'Open Dialog' button will create and open the 'modal' Dialog at top of your Main window component.

Of course you have to adjust "MyDialog.qml" file to fit your design requirements on your own.

However, using this as a 'real' Dialog does also work (for me) like G.M has already pointed out in the comments section:

DialogQt.qml

```
Dialog {
    visible: true
    title: "Blue sky dialog"

    modality : Qt.ApplicationModal

    contentItem: Rectangle {
        color: "lightskyblue"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            text: "Hello blue sky!"
            color: "navy"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess I haven't communicated what I'm trying to do properly. I can easily do what you're doing in your answer here - pop a rectangle in the middle of my main window and interact with it or the window underneath. This is just standard QML layout stuff. I am trying to achieve this with a separate window - something that your DialogQt.qml also does not achieve since it is modal (I need a separate window that is non-modal but always-on-top of my main window).

Comment: @MusiGenesis Do you have to use `Dialog` ? Is using `Window` instead would work ? I've done this exact same thing (non-modal but always-on-top) in my application with a `Window`.

Comment: @Blabdouze: I did try earlier using a `Window` instead of a `Dialog`, but the `createComponent` call kept failing, saying there was no such property on Window as `flags:` or `modality:`, both of which I would have to set to get this to work (I assume). I'm on Qt 5.5, maybe that's my problem? Could you post an answer using `Window`?

Comment: @MusiGenesis I don't think that the version is an issue, if I recall correctly I was using 5.3 at the time and I had a `Window` with flags. I posted a solution that works for me (on 5.7, but I don't think this is a version issue).